# Find the location nearest to current location from an array of locations using Google Maps Places API

Tags: java, android, google-places-api, google-maps-android-api-2

I have an `array` containing different `locations' addresses`. I have also retrieved the current location of user.

Out of all the locations in array, i would like to find the one which is `nearest`. One way could be to compare `Lat-Long` of all but is there some other way to go about it?

***Note:*** I am `not performing nearby location search` to retrieve the adresses. Just assume i already have them stored in an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Location](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html) to determine the distance between two addresses:

```
private static float distance(LatLng current, LatLng last){
    if(last==null)
        return 0;
    Location cL = new Location("");
    cL.setLatitude(current.latitude);
    cL.setLongitude(current.longitude);

    Location lL = new Location("");
    lL.setLatitude(last.latitude);
    lL.setLongitude(last.longitude);

    return lL.distanceTo(cL);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. After finding the distance, i stored all of them in an `arrayList` and then found `min` using `Collections.min()`. But now how do i keep track of LatLng which corresponds to this min distance?

Answer (score 0):

If you need the real nearest location, use [`Location.distanceBetween`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween%28double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float%5b%5d%29).

If you have a lot of locations and require code to execute faster, I'd suggest using this formula:

```
double diffLat = Math.abs(lat1 - lat2);
double diffLng = Math.abs(lng1 - lng2);
if (diffLng > 180) {
    diffLng = 360 - diffLng;
}
double distanceSquared = diffLat * diffLat + diffLng * diffLng;
```

Don't calculate sqrt of this, as this is not needed to find (approximatelly) the closest location. Just compare squared values.

The `if` is there because you may have location with -179 and +179 longitude and these are close to each other.

Depending on the data, you may also try algorithms with binary search on sorted data, but there are 2 dimensions here, so it's not as straightforward as finding `int` in sorted `int[]`.